# Passing an argument to a event listener from dynamically created buttons

Tags: javascript

I'm dynamically creating 3 buttons. How can I pass an argument to`handlerX`?

So basically I want the values in the category Array to be passed on to the `handlerX` eventListener. 
Example:
When `myBtn1` is clicked, I want the alert to be "fur_", 
When `myBtn3` is clicked, I want the alert to be "fas_"

```
var btns = '';
var category = ["fur_", "fts_", "fas_"];
for (i = 1; i < category.length; i++) {
    btns += '<button type="button" class=' + category[i] + ' id= "myBtn' + i + '">.....</button>';
}
var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.innerHTML = btns;

var handlerX = function () {
    alert('Clicked'); //get value from the 'category' Array
};
var buttons = div.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handlerX, false);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're willing to extract it from the `class` attribute, then:

```
var handlerX = function () {
    alert(this.getAttribute('class'));
};
```

Or you better associate it with some `data-` attribute. For example:

```
for (i = 1; i < category.length; i++) {
    btns += '<button type="button" data-category="' + category[i] + '" class=' + category[i] + ' id= "myBtn' + i + '">.....</button>';
}
```

Then:

```
var handlerX = function () {
    alert(this.getAttribute('data-category'));
};
```

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rw21tv1x/2/)

Comment: thanks. But I've got multiple classes within the button. I need to get only what's in the array.

Answer (score 1):

The answers given so far are good and should solve your problem. Just thought I'd add this one because I think it's a solution more in line with what you were asking for: Make your `handlerX` return a function like so:

```
var handlerX = function (param) {
    return function() {alert(param);};
};
var buttons = div.querySelectorAll('button');
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', handlerX(category[i]), false);
}
```

Edit: Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csxgL8qy/)

Comment: that's cool. thanks. Do you see any downsides using `handlerX(category[i])` to pass the value?

Comment: Possibly in debugging, because it's easier to see a `data-` attribute than a parameterized handler. Other than that, I can't think of any.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:
then i would reccomend adding an attibute: data-category="fur_" for example, and access that from your event handler:

```
this.getAttribute('data-category')
```

in hadlerX there is a "this" that is the element that was clicked. You can access its getAttribute("class") to get the class EDIT:this, not self

Comment: thanks. But I've got multiple classes within the button. I need to get only what's in the array.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment(),
  categories = ["fur_", "fts_", "fas_"],
  btn;

function onClickBtn() {
  alert(this.getAttribute("data-category"));
}

for (var i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
  btn = document.createElement("button");
  btn.id = "myBtn" + string(i);
  btn.setAttribute("data-category", category[i]);
  btn.addEventListener("click", onClickBtn);
  fragment.appendChild(btn);
}

var div = document.getElementById('div');
div.appendChild(fragment);
```